# Xcode on a classroom image asks students for admin password

Tags: xcode

I'm teaching a college class, and IT has installed Xcode on the image for the iMacs in the classroom/lab. In theory we should be good to go.

However, when running a project or playground, there are multiple dialog boxes that pop up asking the students for admin passwords. Here is a screenshot of one of the dialogs from a student:

[image: Developer Tools Access dialog]

An administrator was present during the first class to enter these for students, and he and I had tested that future logins on the same machine by a different user should no longer prompt the request for this information. However, students are continuing to report that they are running into these dialogs intermittently. I need to resolve this problem to ensure students can complete their coursework.

Is there a way to install Xcode on an image such that it doesn't perpetually ask users for an admin password?

Comment: Are the students part of the "Developer Tools" group on the Macs in question? If not, adding them would be the first step I would take here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add users you would like to have access to debugging to the `_developer` group.

```
dseditgroup -o edit -u adminusername -t user -a studentusername _developer
```

Replace ‘adminusername’ with the username of a sudoer you have the password to and ‘studentusername’ with the username of an account to add to the group.

Comment: Thank you @grgarside! I also discovered that the following work:

Add all members of a particular Active Directory group to the _developer group: `sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a “domainname\ADGroupName” -t group _developer`

Just add every possible user to the _developer group: `sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a everyone -t group _developer`